# How to migrate to typescript for function taking object parameters with function properties returning differently

Tags: typescript

I am trying to migrate the following `covert` javascript function to typescript, but with no luck, anyone can help, thanks.

```
const convert = (state, obj) => {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(
    (aggr, key) => ({ ...aggr, [key]: () => obj[key](state) }), 
    {}
  )
 }

convert(
  { name: 'ron', id: 123 }, 
  { 
    getName: state => state.name,
    getId: state => state.id
  }
) // newObj: {getName: () => 'ron'}
```

I tried the following, but not working:

```
function convert<State, TObj> : {
  [key in keyof TObj]: ()=>ReturnType<TObj[key]>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a start for you. It is also [in the playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=2&ssc=40&pln=2&pc=48#code/PQKhCgAIUhlBLAdgYwKaQAYHsBGArDSVADwBdVEATAZ0wCVVksAnSgHmtOaQHMAaSADEArilLwsiAHwYBAd3QBrRFjmRSACwCGpdRvQZFqAJ4YoMAG5aANsNS058a9cg50WAGbrjABwOduRB5CLSo9HT10K1t7SIBbalRrC1jHZ1dUc0gPUWRxSVpNCK1kNB9dTXROHXRQykhmVFJhZkRIaiw4po1eSFFlVUQAOnNgcCZETkgJlOZSACZIAF5INihIABVYUhq%20dY2AeXwiMgoaSAYmVg4uXgEACmryAC5N7ZqASmWpPsQBuWk4Ck93WT1Qry2O3Ie0gkFweAhRzw4C%20Sx%20AG91o1mq1IEjGKQhkZjNR7vCPkNGpRhGgQbDYfctDweMwBMTUT97ujIENeUyWQIANrEgC6r3uHLh%20GFJhFjyhqC%20AF8PjD6eilesPgBucBK3XjSSzBZ0yDcxBaLqvABEzEk1oE8EorwAjPMAMyQJVqzH0yA8JoAOUt4PaCu%20YZqQwtXTVsIDpAAks7I%20QI2Chk645BQBA-dBNvpIPA4j5rKguogoRI2p5MAnBFgsIR4LRQkRmHbWZA5D1kBpiw5tLoFD3QqRswW3MgtMJEpgPE3CJQsLEVLoSK3dEhIqnUCN8yAxn6G03XmD0wqhousOtNTrwEA).

```
/**
 * Since `obj` extends `Record<string, Function>`, we know that the `key`
 * values will be of type `string` and that the values themselves will be
 * functions that accept the state and return something unknown.
 */
const convert2 = <
  TState,
  TObj extends Record<string, (state: TState) => unknown>
>(
  state: TState,
  obj: TObj
) => {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce(
    (aggr, key) => ({ ...aggr, [key]: () => obj[key](state) }),
    {}
  );
};

convert2(
  { name: "ron", id: 123 },
  {
    getName: state => state.name,
    getId: state => state.id,
    /**
     * The implementation of `getFoo` is an error, which is what we want,
     * because `foo` does not exist in the state.
     */
    getFoo: state => state.foo
  }
);
```

Comment: Great, nearly perfect. Based on your answer, I got scripts here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FAFwngDgpgBAigVygJzAHgMogIYigPhgF4YAKAZxzwC4YtcoBKYwhAOwGs2B7AdzeDAAZuwDGIAJbc2MUdIBuKEJipQANDADyAIwBWMKAA88bACbkYAJShzkptJWQS2Acw2IU6enny+Kq2m91GG49Wh1dRloAb2AYeJgAbQ4YZxgOKDBuIS09AF1aUmYiQmsQBGQ2ABVIKDQI5Lz8YABfGGiYOITkKHLK3N0bEAA6DLByUlDI4Z7TBFEoUi6EhNJsFxdkDTHiwlIO4cP1zY1kzIKyXZC9M7A8-wZmFsY1ZZX2tuwLDuTUmTHsgMLkUWFZehVqrV6jcOE0YC03oxWoI5GxKCFiLIFEp9jA2NgALZQWgAcmQ0hJ8I0HRcvQAcoTiTBKAxQSy8MN8UT4UjUeRuAAbKDDAXcFyTYa0kAMolFJHAIA
The only concerns is the 2nd param have to use `as` .

Comment: The key things I learned are `Record` and `unknown`, really powerful. Thanks.